# Streaming recorded video

Tags: streaming

What do I need to do in order to stream recorded videos?

I have worked with recording and streaming video contents in real time. I've also worked with VOD application. But I seem to not find much resource on how can I stream recorded content. It would work like a TV with schedules etc, except that it is hosted on the internet.

*Edit:* In case it is not clear enough, I want to *schedule* streaming.

Answer (score 1):

Host your videos on Rackspace or AWS (both of them provide streaming links). Share this content on your site using a HTML based player like videojs.com

Answer (score 0):

You can try Wowza and Darwin Streaming Server maybe...